# Newtonsoft.Json - Dynamic object property access

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to go through every property on a `dynamic` object contained in a `JArray`:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray feeds = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(response.Content);
if (feeds.Any())
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection dynamicProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(feeds.First());
    foreach (dynamic feed in feeds)
    {
        object[] args = new object[dynamicProperties.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in dynamicProperties)
        {
             args[i++] = feed.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(feed, null);
        }
        yield return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
    }
}
```

When i triy to access`feed.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(feed, null);` it tells me that `feed.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);` is null.

JSON structure looks like:

```
[
    {
        "digitalInput.field.channel":"tv",
        "digitalInput.field.comment":"archive",
        "count(digitalInput.field.comment)":130
    }
]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You may add your JSON data as well - otherwise everyone is shooting in the dark.

Comment: I do not know why are you are moving up the tree again at your loop. What exactly do you want to achieve and is outside of prop.GetValue() and prop.GetType()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your foreach to

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in dynamicProperties)
{
    args[i++] = prop.GetValue(feed);
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
args[i++] = feed.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(feed, null);
```

So, lets see on it step by step:

- `feed.GetType()`:  will return type `JArray`
- `feed.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name)`: the problem is here, because

  You tried to get propery of type `JArray` by name, but 
  `prop.Name` in your case will be *"digitalInput.field.channel"*, *"digitalInput.field.comment"* and *"count(digitalInput.field.comment)"* 
  So, in a result it will return `null` because type `JArray` doesn't have such properties.

Comment: Ooowww! Why on earth `prop.GetValue(feed)` works and `feed.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(feed, null);` doesn't!?

Comment: Could you give me a help on this other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908078/create-a-new-anonymoustype-instance/36908265?noredirect=1#comment61379804_36908265)?